# Split an sql column into two based on another columns values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL DB setup like this:

#1 Format

| COLUMN 1 (Values) | COLUMN 2 (Identifier) |
| --- | --- |
| Title_Name | Collection_Title |
| Title_Name | Collection_Title |
| Image_URL | Collection_Image |
| Image_URL | Collection_Image |

I would like to split these 2 columns into four seperate columns like so:

#2 Format

| VALUE #1 | IDENTIFIER #1 | VALUE #2 | IDENTIFIER #2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Image_URL | Collection_Image | Title Name | Collection_Title |
| Image_URL | Collection_Image | Title Name | Collection_Title |

So far I have the query:

```
SELECT  value, identifier
FROM [tableName]
WHERE identifier IN ('Image_URL', 'Title_Name');
```

and its returning the #1 format, so I have all the information returning from the query.
My problem is I would like to have it presented in the #2 Query with each column having a unique name.

How can I expand or improve my query to return the #2 format?

Thank you :)

Comment: It is not possible because your schema have not condition to link Image_URL with Title_Name in single row

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you mean. You are saying that to split these two columns into four is not possible?

Comment: How do you determine that Image_URL from first table, third row goes to the result table, first row in result and not second?

Comment: Hi BoogaBooga, does it matter which title name is in the same row with which Imgage_URL? or can they be matched randomly?

Comment: They can be matched randomly, for my purposes its important that all the 'Image_URL's are in one column and all the 'Title_Name's are in another. With my current query I have them alternating in the same column.

Comment: What should be in case when count of Image_URL not equal to count of Title_Name?

Comment: If I understand you correctly what should happen when there is a Title_Name but NOT an Image_URL? 
a null can be put in the spot, that is ok.

Comment: I think some *actual* sample data and expected results is required here to understand how to split and join this data, or is "image_URL" the *actual* repeating data?

Comment: Sorry if the question is unclear.
 #1 format is how the data is stored in the DB. 
I would like to return it in #2 format. 
So when identifier='Collection_Title' return its value and when identifier='Image_URL' return its value, but in seperate columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` and get cartesian :

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT  value, identifier
  FROM [tableName]
  WHERE identifier = 'Collection_Image'
) Images
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT  value, identifier
  FROM [tableName]
  WHERE identifier = 'Collection_Title'
) Titles;
```

Result:

```
+============+==================+=============+==================+
| value      | identifier       | value       | identifier       |
+============+==================+=============+==================+
| Image_URL1 | Collection_Image | Title_Name1 | Collection_Title |
+------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
| Image_URL2 | Collection_Image | Title_Name1 | Collection_Title |
+------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
| Image_URL1 | Collection_Image | Title_Name2 | Collection_Title |
+------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
| Image_URL2 | Collection_Image | Title_Name2 | Collection_Title |
+------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

[SQL cartesian fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2017/ce7fcf69087ca3da470054e4c6b6e41d/)

You also can use `ROW_NUMBER` function as join condition :

```
SELECT Images.value, Images.identifier, Titles.value, Titles.identifier  
FROM (
  SELECT  value, identifier, row_number() over(order by value) rn
  FROM [tableName]
  WHERE identifier = 'Collection_Image'
) Images
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT  value, identifier, row_number() over(order by value) rn
  FROM [tableName]
  WHERE identifier = 'Collection_Title'
) Titles ON Images.rn = Titles.rn;
```

[FULL OUTER JOIN](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2017/6efa45ea0b7445abd868bc29780da8ff/)

Comment: Thank you Slava yes this did the trick! Could you maybe help me further by explaining your thought process a little?

If I understand it correctly you essentially built two queries and then combined them together?

Comment: Yes, you right. 2 queries generates 2 data sets and join combine their. Look one more example with FULL OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a sequential number to each group of values and use a *full join*. this will give the exact results or *null* if there are an imbalance of matching rows.

```
with image as (
    select [value] Value1, identifier Identifier1, Row_Number() over(order by value) rn
    from t
    where [value] = 'Image_URL'
), title as (
    select [value] Value2, identifier Identifier2, Row_Number() over(order by value) rn
    from t
    where [value] = 'Title_Name'
)
select  value1,identifier1, value2, identifier2
from image i 
full join title t on t.rn=i.rn
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=67d1be57f955099317288f03c6d5809b)

Note this demo is using Sql Server (no specific RDBMS was indicated) but is compatible with most.

Comment: Hi Stu thanks for your answer Im working on implementing it :)